# jquery url path loading not work without page extension

Tags: jquery

i have code jquery code to load the data on scroll here is the function

```
 function GetRecords() {
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

if you see the url, it works when i write default.aspx/getcustomer but it does not work when i have page path without extension like url:default/getcustomer

Please advice

Comment: use absolute url path in ajax call

Comment: please advice how the code should,

Comment: what should i change here url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",

Comment: write the complete path like: http://example.com/pathabc/1/2/Default.aspx/GetCustomers in your ajax call

Comment: not working same error "Undefined"

Comment: What response does the browser indicate for the AJAX call? (as in, in Chrome on the calling page hit F12 and click the Network tab, click your calling function and examine what the response is)

Comment: it says Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Default:14

Comment: in firefox it says this typeof JSON!="undefined"&&(window._vwdJSON=JSON),typeof define!="undefined"&&(window._vwdDefine=define,define=null)

Comment: `$ is not defined` means you haven't loaded the jQuery library.

Comment: `data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',` is not valid JSON. Use `data: JSON.stringify({ pageIndex: pageIndex})`